# Using the hrtimer callback function, is it possible to give function parameters?

Tags: linux, parameters, callback

So if I use like:

```
.............................

enum hrtimer_restart my_hrtimer_callback( struct hrtimer *timer )

.............................

hr_timer.function = &my_hrtimer_callback;
...............................
hrtimer_start(hr_timer,ktime,HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
...............................
```

Is it possible to pass any parameters to the callback function during the start of the timer?  I google a little bit but didn't find a clue. How to use that?

Thanks;>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embed the `struct hrtimer` in a structure of your creation that has any additional information you may need. Then use [`container_of()`](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html) to get the pointer to the containing structure from the `timer` argument.